# Undefined Value For Response Body in Node.js in an Exports Function.

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a controller accessed from a route through a

```
router.post('/human',human.create);
```

human is imported through its controller file which contains the following :

```
var config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config'),
logger = require(__dirname + '/../lib/logger'),
util = require(__dirname + '/../helpers/util');

exports.create = function(request, response, next){


response.send({

  id: "human_103tsG2eZvKYlo2CW5yEDyUe",
  firstName: "Patricia",
  middleName: null,
  lastName: "Cesar",
  sex: "Female",
  birthdate: null

});

};
```

Inside this create function, I can do

```
console.log(request);
```

And a humongous JSON object will apear in the terminal, including the attribute I need : body.

However, when I do, `console.log(request.body)`, it goes undefined.

Am I missing a particular functionality of Node or Express that needs to be coded out?

Comment: It is impossible. Can you please show the piece of JSON where `body` is visible?

Comment: Did you try to add app.use(express.bodyParser());

Comment: It's too long it don't fit in the comment section. Here's a segment though : 


{
....
    pathname: '/human',
        path: '/human',
        href: '/human' },
     params: {},
     query: {},
     res: [Circular],
     next: [Function: next],
     _startTime: Wed May 07 2014 12:53:38 GMT+0800 (PHT),
     _remoteAddress: '127.0.0.1',
     body: { name: 'Jekri' },
     _body: true,
     pipe: [Function],
     addListener: [Function],
     on: [Function],
     pause: [Function],
     resume: [Function],
     read: [Function],
     secret: 'c38b1c9ac1c2f9d442f17bb2b77d1a075b617715',

....
}

Comment: @shredmill

app.use(require('body-parser')({uploadDir : config.temp_dir}));

^A different one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the express 4.x which decoupled lots of middleware packages, as @shredmill metioned, you should use

```
bodyParser = require ('body-parser')

...

app.use(bodyParser.json()); //i found this works for me comparing to use bodyParser()
```

Answer (score 0):

`req.body` is not pre-parsed for you automatically. You should explicitly use the `connect.json()` middleware for this:

```
var connect = require('connect');
router.post('/human', connect.json(), human.create);
```